# messageIn does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a code looks like the following.

I get message from query string. After that I'm going to get it that to message `array(msg_arr)`.But all of these things in inside the `Page_load`.

But why does this error show?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {
            string messageIn = Request.QueryString["msg"];  
            // some code here
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

        string[] msg_arr = messageIn.Split(' '); // error shown here
        int size = msg_arr.Length;

        if(!CheckUserExistAndReporter("messageIn"))
        {
           // Response.Redirect("~/test.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
```

Comment: Please show the errormessage too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring the `messageIn` variable inside the `try{}` block and hence its scope is only within the `try{}` block.

You should do something like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string messageIn=string.Empty;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {

             messageIn = Request.QueryString["msg"];

            // some code here


        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }


        string[] msg_arr = messageIn.Split(' '); // error shown here
        int size = msg_arr.Length;

        if(!CheckUserExistAndReporter("messageIn"))
        {
           // Response.Redirect("~/test.aspx");
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

You declared `messageIn`  inside the try-block, that's your problem.

Just declare it outside:

```
string messageIn = null;
try
{
    messageIn = Request.QueryString["msg"];
    // some code here
}

...
```

The `try`-block creates a new scope, so variables declared inside it are not visible outside.

Answer (score 4):

When you do this

```
try
{
 string messageIn = Request.QueryString["msg"];

 // some code here

 }
```

the scope of the string is restricted to the try block and it no longer exists outside that block.

you will have to increase the scope of your string say to the entire if block for it to work

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
string messageIn = string.Empty;
......
try
{
messageIn = Request.QueryString["msg"];
// some code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare  `string messageIn` outside the block.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string messageIn=string.Empty;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You getting your error because you declared `messageIn` inside your try block. Try This:

```
string messageIn;
try
{
   messageIn = Request.QueryString["msg"];
   // some code here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  Response.Write(ex.Message);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageIn)
{
   string[] msg_arr = messageIn.Split(' ');
   ...
}
```